# how to read a webform with php

Tags: php

I am trying to do something really basic but can not seem to find a tutorial for it.

I have created a simple web form using HTML what I need todo is create a php file that will read the web form, open a new browser window (or display in same page) the contents of the web form, do toy guys have any tutorials on this?

Many thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure many will post different links to tutorials that they like, but I thought I would just give you the basic. The key parts to the form are the method and action. The Method attribute tells ths browser how to submit the data, either through GET or POST. The action attribute tells the browser where to submit the form. (In your case it will be, somepage.php) If you ever need the form to submit back to itself, you can here use explicitly type the page name or you can use use PHP to  [dynamically insert the page name](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Finally, make sure that all your form fields use the name attribute, as this is how php will access the elements.

On the php side of things, your form variables will be stored in either $_GET or $_POST depending on how on method you used to submit your form. For example, assume you have a input element of type text with the name 'FirstName'. Within php you can access this by doing

```
<?php
    var firstName = $_GET['FirstName'];
?>
```

This should be enough to get you started. Be sure to check out the php docs and the other tutorials listed on this page for a more details.

Comment: How would I like the script to my Submit button on my html page sp that it runs the php code??

Comment: Chris, there is no need to, that is if the button is between the form tags. The browser's html renderer knows that a submit button "submits" a form. On submit button click, the browser will say "ok this person wants to submit this form, how do I submit it (the method attribute) and where do I submit it to (the action method)."

outside of the form tag, you would need to do this via javascript just calling document.form['name'].submit

Comment: Thank you very Scott! and to all those who gave me tutorial webbies :)!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this tutorial: http://www.learnphp-tutorial.com/HtmlForms.cfm

And you can find many more tutorials if you search it on Google.

Answer (score 0):

This should help : http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/php-forms.aspx