# Members only section for a website

Tags: php

I am trying to make a members only section on a website. The user has to enter his username and password to get logged on. I have set up the registration section for the users and they are able to create an account on my website.

Also as shown in the code below I am able to navigate to the user's only section of the website. However the problem is that I need to pass the value **$myusername** to the page  **members_area.php** so that I can do some database queries on that page. How do I do that ?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email= '$myusername' and password='$mypassword'" ;
$result=mysql_query($sql,$ms);

$user_exist = mysql_num_rows($result);

// if the user is there in the database
if($user_exist>0){ 

    //start a session over here
    $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $myusername;
    Header('Location: members_area.php');
}
```

Comment: Is your question how to read the values of an HTML input form posted from the previous page?

Comment: If so, maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449775/how-to-read-a-webform-with-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have several options. Only a few are good.

Since you just stored $myusername in a session variable, you can reference that on members_area.php:

```
session_start(); // Don't forget this on each page that uses sessions
$myusername = $_SESSION["valid_user"];
```

That would be the more secure way, given what you've suggested here. Other options involve passing the value with a query string in the URL:

```
header("Location: members_area.php?user=$myusername");
```

But this isn't secure and is quite subject to folly. Just FYI it can be done.

However, as a side-note, I might suggest you store a unique identifier (UID or GUID) for each user. It's just a number that only that user has which uniquely identifies it. You'll find it is more robust.

Answer (score 5):

Ad this to the top of members_area.php

```
session_start();
$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email= '{$_SESSION['valid_user']}'" ;
$result=mysql_query($sql,$ms);
if( !mysql_num_rows($result) ) die( 'Please log in first' );


// The global variable $_SESSION['valid_user'] will contain the username var (email)
```